# CodeIgniter and base_url(), form submission issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-3

my earlier issue was solved which spoke about base_url duplication in CodeIgniter. However, after editing base_url() as base_url = "http://example.com/myapp/", form submission does not load my thank you page. I have checked it with Firebug, there is a Response: 200 OK coming. But my view register-done.php does not load no matter what I do. The form just stays there. Doesn't move, though the data goes to database and registered. Before this fix, it was working fine. here is the html of form-submission:

```
<div class="section-title">Personal Details</div>
<form id="profile-image-form" method="post" action="<?= base_url() ?>signup" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<img src="<?= asset_url() ?>css/images/grey-bg.png" width="128" class="profile-pic"/>
<button type="button" id="upload-supplier-user-image-button" class="no-btn-style" onclick="$('#profile_image').click()">Upload User Image</button>
<img style="display:none; width: 35px;" src="<?= asset_url()?>images/upload-loading.gif" id="supplier-profile-upload-gif"/>
<input type="file" name="image" id="profile_image" style="display: none"/>
</form>

<form id="register-company-form" method="post" action="<?= base_url() ?>signup/supplier" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="hidden" name="image" id="image" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="text-field"/>
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="text-field"/>
<input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" class="text-field"/>
<input type="email" id="personal_email" name="personal_email" class="text-field"/>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="text-field"/>
<input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" class="text-field"/>
<input type="text" id="job" name="job" class="text-field"/>
<input type="submit" name="sign-up-personal" id="sign-up-personal" class="btn-purple supplier-login-btn" value="Sign Up"/>
<input type="text" id="company_name" name="company_name" class="text-field"/>
<input type="text" id="address_one" name="address_one" class="text-field"/>
<input type="text" id="address_two" name="address_two" class="text-field"/>
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your city"  type="text" class="text-field" required autocomplete="off"/>
<input id="city" type="hidden" value="" name="city" required>
<input id="country" type="hidden" value="" name="country" required>
<button type="button" class="btn-purple supplier-login-btn" onclick="$('#company_logo_file').click()">Browse</button>
<input type="hidden" id="company_logo" name="company_logo" value=""/>
<textarea id="company_description" name="company_description" class="textarea-field"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="company_website" name="company_website" class="text-field"/>
<input type="email" id="company_email" name="company_email" class="text-field"/>
<input type="text" id="company_telephone" name="company_telephone" class="text-field"/>
<button type="button" class="btn-purple supplier-login-btn" onclick="$('#trade_license').click()">Browse</button>
<input type="file" id="trade_license" name="trade_license" class="text-field hidden" accept="application/pdf"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="yes"/> By Signing up, I agree to  <span class="terms-of-service">terms of service</span>
<input type="submit" name="sign-up" id="sign-up" class="btn-purple supplier-login-btn" value="Sign Up"/>
</form>

<form id="company_logo_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" style="display: none" name="company_logo_file" id="company_logo_file" accept="image/*"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
    return arg != value;
}, "Value must not equal arg.");

var validator = $('#register-company-form').validate({
    /* some validation */
submitHandler: function(form) {
var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
$.ajax({
type: $(form).attr('method'),
url: $(form).attr('action'),
data: formData,
dataType : 'json',
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
})
.done(function (response) {
window.location.href = '<?= base_url() ?>supplier/successful';
});
});
</script>
```

and here is the signup controller. I have changed nothing, but it stopped sending form to the database :( Any help will be highly appreciated. @DFriend

```
<?php 
class Signup extends CI_Controller {
private $return_data = NULL;
private $return_status = 200;
private $return_message = NULL;
public function index(){
$this->load->model('CaptchaModel');
$this->load->helper('Captcha');
$cid = $this->input->post('cid');
$captcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
$captcha_exist = $this->CaptchaModel->check_captcha($captcha, $cid);
if($captcha_exist)
{
$this->load->model('RegisterModel');
$image = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('image'));
$title = $this->input->post('title');
$first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
$last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
$user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$gender = $this->input->post('gender');
$mobile = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('mobile'));
$dob_day = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('dob_day'));
$dob_month = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('dob_month'));
$dob_year = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('dob_year'));
if($dob_day != '' && $dob_month != '' && $dob_year != ''){
$date_of_birth = new DateTime($dob_year . '-' . $dob_month . '-' . $dob_day);
}
else
{
$date_of_birth = '';
}
$country = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('country'));
$city = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('city'));
$interests = $this->input->post('interests');
$habits = $this->input->post('habits');
$comment = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('comments'));
$newsletter = parent::check_user_input($this->input->post('newsletter'));
$registration = $this->RegisterModel->register($image, $title, $first_name, $last_name, $user_name, $email, $password, $mobile, $date_of_birth, $country, $city, $interests, $habits, $comment, $newsletter, $gender);
if($registration == -1)
{
$this->return_status = 400;
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, $this->return_status, $this->return_message);
}
elseif
($registration == -2)
{
$this->return_status = 401;
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, $this->return_status, $this->return_message);
}elseif
($registration){
$this->load->library('session');
$user_data = array('login' => 1,'uid' => $registration);
$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, $this->return_status, $this->return_message);
}
else
{
$this->return_status = 500;
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, $this->return_status, $this->return_message);
}
} 
else 
{
$this->return_status = 600;
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, $this->return_status, $this->return_message);
}
}

public function supplier()
{
$file_element_name = 'trade_license';
$this->load->model('RegisterModel');

$profile_image_form = $this->input->post('image');
$title = $this->input->post('title');
$first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
$last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
$user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
$email = $this->input->post('personal_email');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$job = $this->input->post('job');
$company_name = $this->input->post('company_name');
$address_one = $this->input->post('address_one');
$address_two = $this->input->post('address_two');
$country = $this->input->post('country');
$city = $this->input->post('city');
$company_description = $this->input->post('company_description');
$company_website = $this->input->post('company_website');
$company_email = $this->input->post('company_email');
$company_telephone = $this->input->post('company_telephone');
$company_logo = $this->input->post('company_logo');
$trade_license = '';

$config['upload_path'] = './assets/license/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
{
$status = 'error';
$msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
}
else
{
$data = $this->upload->data();
$status = "success";
$msg = '';
$trade_license = $data['file_name'];
}
$profile_image = $profile_image_form;
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/profile/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($profile_image_form))
{
$status = 'error';
$msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
}
else
{
$data = $this->upload->data();
$status = "success";
$msg = '';
$profile_image = $data['file_name'];
}
$email_found = $this->db->get_where("supplier_user", array("company_email" => $email));
if($email_found->result_id->num_rows > 0) {
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, 401, $this->return_message);
} 
else 
{
$email_found_2 = $this->db->get_where("supplier_user", array("email" => $email));
if($email_found_2->result_id->num_rows > 0) {
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, 402, $this->return_message);
} 
else
{
$username_found = $this->db->get_where("supplier_user", array("user_name" => $user_name));
if($username_found->result_id->num_rows > 0) {
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, 403, $this->return_message); } 
else 
{
$this->RegisterModel->register_supplier($profile_image, $title, $first_name, $last_name, $user_name, $email, $password, $job, $company_name, $address_one, $address_two, $country, $city, $company_description, $company_website, $company_email, $company_telephone, $company_logo, $trade_license);
parent::returnJson($this->return_data, $this->return_status, $this->return_message);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: I believe that `$config['base_url']` needs to point the domain and path to your installation. ie. `$config['base_url'] =  'www.example.com'` With your .htaccess entries I don't think you need to add the path. Try it both with and without `'/myapp/"`

Comment: wow. Amazing @DFriend This work liked a charm. You are a life saver. Since how long I've been trying this and I did every possible thing. But this worked. Thank you my friend.

Comment: But now I have another problem. my user registration view loads, but doesn't do anyting after inputting data. It worked before this change. I don't know whats wrong! Any help please?

Comment: Will need to see more code in order to comment. Specifically the controller/function that handles the submit. The form html wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Edit your question with this code. No one can't handle it this way.

Comment: Got to agree with @Tpojka said. It's really hard to read code in comments.

First thing to check is to look at the source once it is loaded in the browser and check that the <form> action attributes look right.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion @DFriend and Tpojka 
I have edited my question with the code changes. Kindly look into that. Thank you for this help.

Comment: The first thing you need to confirm is that the "action" attribute of the "<form ..." element looks good after the page loads. Because of the trouble you were having with `base_url()` it seems like a good place to start. Unless the action is valid nothing is going to happen on submit.

Comment: Thanks for comment @DFriend I managed to get the form submitted. However, now the view which is supposed to return in successful submission is not loaded. A user gets registered, also in database it is inserted, but user doesn't get any response. The form doesn't move no matter what I do. I have also debugged in Firebug. It is sending success response: 200 OK. but the view register-done.php is not loaded.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but supplier() returns a JSON response. Right? I don't see where this response is being handled besides the $.ajax call on your forms view. If there is other (not shown) javaScript that handles the response from supplier() that's where you should look first.

Comment: Yes, @DFriend it returns a Json response, and the response where its handled it right at the bottom in bottom of html section above. Let me copy for you: .
`.done(function (response) {
window.location.href = '<?= base_url() ?>supplier/successful';
});`

Comment: Thanks @Zafar I needed that confirmed. And the controller `supplier` has a function called `successful`? Or is that URL redefined in routes.php? If so, how is it redefined?

Comment: Thank you @DFriend for quick response. Yes, controller supplier has the function called successful, which does nothing but loads the view $this->load->view('supplier/sucesss')

Comment: here is the route:
$route['registration_successful'] = 'page/index/register-done';

Comment: This is the response returned from controller: {"Response":200," Data":null,"Message":null}

Comment: Hello @DFriend seems like this JSON is not working: '.done(function (response) { window.location.href = '<?= base_url() ?>supplier/successful'; });' because I put an alert() into this instead of view, but it returned nothing. the response is also html but in json format. Strange! Clueless.

Comment: So `.done(...` does not get called? Is that what you are saying? The alert does not fire?

Comment: Exactly!  done(..) does not get called.

Comment: Hi @DFriend I have added this as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321037/ajax-done-dont-work-together-for-me 
can you please respond and help? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there is an issue with your .htaccess file. if you do not want to remove index.php file from the url you can use site_url() instead of base_url.Here is the difference b/w both

```
base_url() = http://yourwebsite.com/
```

whereas

```
site_url() = http://yourwebsite.com/index.php
```

to remove index.php file from url put this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

read this  tutorial for more
http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url/

Comment: Thanks @Ricky It has been solved by changing base_url()= '/myapp' to base_url = "http://example.com/myapp/  The answer was contributed by DFriend
However, I have updated my question. After this change, though the app is working, it is not sending registration form. Can you please look into that?

Comment: Read this tutorial might help you http://w3code.in/2015/09/create-login-and-registration-with-codeigniter/