# Ajax .done() don't work together for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I have a very strange situation. I have an AJAX function which sends form data to a php codeigniter controller, on json response, it has to deal with the response. first part is working, but later part, which is a .done() function, doesn't work, no matter what I try.
here is my script:

```
var validator = $('#register-company-form').validate({
    rules: {
        title: {
            required: true,
            valueNotEquals: 0
        },
        /* rules here */
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-field').addClass('error-field');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element){
        $(element).closest('.form-field').removeClass('error-field');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: $(form).attr('method'),
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            $(".form-field").removeClass("error-field");
            $(".item-exists").hide();

            if(response.Response == 401) {
                 $("#company_email").closest('.form-field').addClass('error-field');
                 $("#company_email").closest(".form-field").find(".item-exists").show();
            } else if(response.Response == 402) {
                $("#personal_email").closest('.form-field').addClass('error-field');
                $("#personal_email").closest(".form-field").find(".item-exists").show();
            } else if(response.Response == 403) {
                $("#user_name").closest('.form-field').addClass('error-field');
                $("#user_name").closest(".form-field").find(".item-exists").show();
            } else if(response.Response == 200){
                /* load my view */
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

My PHP script returns following JSON response:

{"Response":200,"Data":null,"Message":null}

After getting this response, my .done() function is supposed to act according to it and load a page, which it is not. I have tried putting console.log() and alert() into it, but now its clear its not responding. Is there any other way to do this or any correction in code?
Please note that the same code really worked fine on another server. This has happened after migration.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: In most browsers you can open the developer tools and look at the request and response to make sure that everything's as expected. Have you done that?

Comment: what does `load a page` mean? Nothing in code shown reflects anything like that

Comment: Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and look into the headers.

Comment: After migration from what to what?

Comment: use complete function into ajax or try success and error

Comment: [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) callbacks are only invoked for `$.ajax()` if the request is considered successful (HTTP status 200 OK, or one of only a few others). If it's not being invoked, then there was an error -- a different status code or jQuery couldn't parse the response. Have you at least tried adding a [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) callback to see what that error may be? The 3rd argument passed to it should give you the `errorThrown` (from [`$.ajax()`'s `error`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

Comment: contentType shouldn't be false - either omit it or set it correctly.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for responses. I have checked the headers in Firebug already. I already copied it in question above: {"Response":200,"Data":null,"Message":null}
which means my php script is sending JSON response above, but some how done is not acting on it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski can you please write here the syntax for .fail()? I have never used it. and load page is actually a html page which it has to load after successful registration. Thank you.

Comment: If `.done()` is not running then the server replied with an HTTP response code value not equal to 200. You need to examine the header.

Comment: @DFriend I have aleady analyzed the headers. Copied it in the question above. It responds with the following JSON: {"Response":200,"Data":null,"Message":null}
Also in firebug, it doesn't appear under JSON tab, but under 'Response' and HTML.  if there was an error, data would not be submitted to database. In this case, it is submitting.

Comment: The JSON response is not what we are interested in. In Firebug from a tab that shows you Headers, expand the Response Headers. The the right of the text "Response Headers" is a link titled "view source" - click that. What is the value in the first item? (it will start with `HTTP/1.1` followed with some other info. if it does not say `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` then `.done()` will not be called.

Comment: What if you `console.log(typeof response, response)` inside the `.done()` callback?

Comment: @DFriend This is the response header, which says 200 OK:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 18:37:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 44
`

Comment: @JoaquínO Thanks for this. Did it. Nothing happened. I am puzzled, why on the earth? Is there anything suppressing the output?

Comment: @Zafar what about `.done(function(response) { alert("Reached here"); alert(typeof response); })`?

Comment: Syntax for .fail  `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});` So try `.fail(function (xhr, txtStatus, errorThrown){ alert('Status: ' + txtStatus + ' error: ' + errorThrown)};});`

Comment: Hi @DFriend this generates a PHP error:
 `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/example/public_html/beta/application/controllers/Signup.php:1)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 564
Backtrace:
File: /home/example/public_html/beta/application/models/Registermodel.php
Line: 226
Function: insert`

Comment: The synatx I used for this .fail with ajax is:
`$.ajax
({ //code here })
.fail(function (xhr, txtStatus, errorThrown)
{ alert('Status: ' + txtStatus + ' error: ' + errorThrown)}
});`

Comment: Hi @DFriend I finally got the .fail working and here is the error generated in alert: `Status: parsererror error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: @Zafar The error is server-side and appears to be that you're using [`header()`](http://php.net/header) after you've already sent some output (`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`). This cannot be done. All headers have to be set before any content is sent to the client. And, jQuery won't be able to make sense out of a PHP error dump when it's expecting JSON, so you'll have to resolve the PHP error first.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks for comment. Please read my last message. The error has been removed. However, it occurs that the whole mess is because server is not sending data in JSON, while $.ajax function expects data in JSON format. this is the message I receive after implementing .fail() function:
`Status: parsererror error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: And guess what I am now doing? hitting my head against the wall trying to get the server pass the JSON data, though the data appear to be JSON, which is, as you saw already: `{"Response":402,"Data":null,"Message":null}` This is valid JSON as I know. But still Jquery doesn't parse it. It thinks its html @DFriend

Comment: I think if you examine the html from the server when you receive the parser error you fill find a nicely formatted PHP Error output. That output is messing with the ajax. There can be only one header sent and the first one out is the PHP error display.  The second output is the JSON package you have reported here. There is something amiss in your controller.

Comment: @Zafar You won't be able to fix the Ajax request without first fixing the PHP script. Because, it's not actually outputting JSON. it may be attempting to, but isn't succeeding due to the error that you quoted before (`Cannot modify header information`). You'll need to fix that error first, then you can see if the Ajax request may be failing for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your Kind information **@DFreind** and **@JonathanLonowski**, with your hints, I finally figured out this problem which took me almost 3 days.
Actually when I looked closely at the html produced by PHP, it said:
    1 {"Response":200,"Data":null,"Message":null}

This '1' before the JSON string was generating cannot modify headers error!
After lots of efforts, I just saw a plain goddamn '1' just before opening `<?php` tag on first line in my controller. Removing this '1' worked like a charm, all errors gone, life saved, dosing in heaven now :-)

**Indication for researchers:** Please install Firebug if you are facing similar errors and always look into response headers, try experimenting. Most of the time PHP errors mess with your output. In my case, 'headers already sent' error generated because before php started its output, html came in. Watch out for any echo() or set_cookie() functions as well!

Thanks all of you StackOverflowish geeks :)